# Get unread notification count using Facebook API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I just want to get the count of unread notifications and unread messages from my personal facebook profile. I know that with v3.2 of Graphs API, this is not possible any more. Any other way I can get this data. I just want to get the count and no other data.

Comment: you basically answered your question already.

Comment: @luschn I mean not so clean way, like something with javascript?

Comment: we don´t discuss "not so clear ways" (aka stuff that is not allowed) on stackoverflow, obviously. rule of thumb: if it´s not possible with the api, don´t do it.

Comment: _“like something with javascript?”_ - in what context, like a browser extension that would get this from the page’s DOM while you are on the page …?

Comment: @04FS yeah maybe something of that kind from DOM.